# WCF Two Way authentication with certificates issue

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, certificate

To test if one way or two way authentication is happening on the client side i've deleted the servers certificate from  trusted people, and the communication is still happening with no issue, so only one way authentication is happening. I've checked on the client with fiddle, and the server is passing on its certificate.

On the server side the certificate is bound to the address and port over IIS so that is why it is not explicitly stated.

Client is running on a VM and server on my local machine.

I've made the certificates with Keystore explorer and CA is placed in trusted root on both. Server certificate (.pfx file) placed in personal on server, clients certificate (.cer file) in trusted people on the server, and just vice versa for these two on the client.

Server:

```
string address = "https://192.168.0.30:8003/Service/";
            Uri uri = new Uri(address);
            IService service = new MessageService();

            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(service, uri);
            host.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerTrust;
  
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();

            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), binding, address);
            host.Open();
```

Client:

```
            var address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://192.168.0.30:8003/Service/"));

            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

            var channel = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, address);

            channel.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerTrust;

            channel.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
                                                                 StoreName.My,
                                                                 X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
                                                                 "192.168.0.39");
            var proxy = channel.CreateChannel();
```

Found many different contradictory answers on what it means for a service to be two way vs one way, theoretically totally clear but programmatically not so much, from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/message-security-with-mutual-certificates) official source ive concluded that message security mode is the two way one and transport a one way authentication mode, but then found that people also make two way authentication with transport security mode

Comment: What's your question? Is it to prove the issue?

Comment: Its how to implement two way authentication  with certificates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve it, the answer is that when using https on the client you need to change from Authentication to SslCertificateAuthentication, because originally the client wasn't even invoking the certificate authentication

```
   channel.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication = new X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication();
   channel.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerTrust;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement bidirectional authentication for wcf, check out these two docs:

This is an [official Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/message-security-with-mutual-certificates?redirectedfrom=MSDN) that lists the server and client presentations and basic configurations.

[This article](http://www.iprogrammable.com/2011/09/08/certificates-2-way-ssl-wcf/) is how to implement wcf bidirectional verification. You can refer to them all.

Comment: The first link is the one i have linked in my post, the second one i have seen before and have done things exactly like that, and it did not solve the issue